# PHP fclose not freeing up memory

Tags: php, memory, fopen, fread, fclose

I have a PHP loop whereby I read and process the contents of several files.

```
<?php
foreach($files as $file)
{
    $f = fopen($file, 'r');
    $content = fread($f, filesize($file));
    import($content);
    fclose($f);
}
?>
```

However, after several iterations of the loop, I am still getting a memory exhausted error on the `fread()` line - my understanding was that using `fclose()` would free up the memory of the resource, but is this not the case?

I have read a number of other questions on the matter and they all referenced using `fclose()`, which I was already doing. I'm also dumping out `memory_get_usage()/memory_get_peak_usage()` and they just keep going up until it fails.

Am I misunderstanding how `fclose()` handles freeing up memory?

Comment: What does `import($content)` do? Maybe that's what's eating up memory.

Comment: Yes, `import()` isn't built-in. Is that function reading all the content from these files and then not freeing it when it's finished? `fclose()` as you have it, will work correctly.

Comment: Hmm, import() just inserts the data to a database, but if I don't call import(), it does get to the end of the foreach loop. What I don't understand though is the content is read with fread() inside the foreach, and just passes it through to import(), so where would I free up the memory?

Comment: Try using `file_get_contents()` instead of `fread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
foreach($files as $file)
{
    $f = fopen($file, 'r');
    $content = fread($f, filesize($file));
    import($content);
    fclose($f); // this close file
    unset($content); // this free memory allocated to content of file
}
?>
```